# Microsoft Outlook 2007 550 Access Denied Error (Not fixable via SMTP check)

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook-2007

So I'm trying to set up a new user's account on Outlook. Pretty straightforward process, except for when it's not. Every time I try to test his account and send a test email message I get the ol 550 Access denied helo error. Now I've tried going into account settings and checking the box for SMTP authentication. That hasn't worked (I should also mention it's unnecessary since I was able to successfully add the account on my computer without having to make the same adjustment. I've also tried changing the .pst file since it was originally trying to write to the previous user's .pst backup).

The computer the new user is using has OS7 home edition on it and is running Outlook 2007. The computer that I'm using which successfully added him is a Windows 7 Professional and uses Outlook 2010. I've also made sure that the ports are successfully aligned so as to not mess with the firewall. The user can receive emails; she just can't send any. Thoughts?

Comment: Could the username or password have a typo in it?

Comment: Nope. That was the first thing I checked. I even reset the user's password.

Comment: What email service/hosting provider are you using?

Comment: Using hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

A “550 Access Denied – Invalid HELO name” SMTP error usually occurs when the SMTP Domain configured as part of an email sender’s identity does not match the senders email address.

**Outlook needs the Outgoing Server Requires Authentication option checked.
550 SMTP Error -or- 550 Sender verify failed
When you get these or other 550 errors, it is best to contact [hostgator via ticket](http://www.hostgator.com/contact.shtml), live chat or phone for assistance.**

Hostgator will also potentially do this if you have not checked for mail on that account using POP or IMAP in the last 30 minutes.

More on 550 errors:

One of the common errors to come across while web hosting is a 550 Error. This error can have many reasons and causes to why it is shown, however, the error itself always indicates one thing, that there is a mail relay error.
Common 550 Error Messages

Mail bounces across several receptors as it sent from sender to recipient, allowing several places where an error can occur should a relay point be out and have an error message be generated. Although there can be a variety of messages generated, HostGator has listed some of the most common messages to accompany a 550 Error.
550 No Such User Here

This error occurs when sending to a remote location while having a DNS zone on the server for the domain set to localdomains or automatically checked.
550 DICTIONARY ATTACK

This error indicated that all email for that account must be stopped from being sent and pause all mailing lists. Then wait one hour. If Outlook was being used, users can try using webmail to send messages.
550 External MTA's must be authenticated in order to send e-mails